How to change the value of a field that is described by DIV role=“textbox” using JS
I have a page on Jira system. And input field on it.
<div class="field-group"><label class="field-label" for="description" id="description-label">Description <span class="vp-optional">(optional)</span></label><div class="field-container"><div class="cp-textarea-control" id="description-textarea-control" data-editorloaderenabled="true"><div class="cp-textarea-loading" style="display: none;"><div class="cp-text-area-loading--icons"></div><aui-spinner size="small" resolved=""><div class="aui-spinner spinner"><svg focusable="false" size="20" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle></svg></div></aui-spinner></div><textarea class="full-width-field textarea" rows="6" cols="10" name="description" id="description" aria-labelledby="description-label" style="display: none;"></textarea><div class="wysiwyg-create-request"><div class="css-1dr2qy6"><div style="display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute;"></div><div class=" css-18w41as"><div class="akEditor css-degu06"><div data-testid="ak-editor-main-toolbar" class="css-17nz5j4"><div class="custom-key-handler-wrapper css-yd211k" role="toolbar" aria-label="Editor toolbar" aria-controls="ak-editor-textarea"><div class="css-1ky3qeu"><div style="display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute;"></div><div class="css-6gmvcx"><span class="css-2i865c"><div class="css-x571cj"><div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Text styles" class="block-type-btn css-1muxtt6" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span class="css-6t6jtt"><span role="img" aria-label="Text styles" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M6.26 6.678l-3.237 9.534a.5.5 0 00.473.66h1.032a.75.75 0 00.717-.53l.648-2.107H9.63l.647 2.107a.75.75 0 00.717.53h1.113a.5.5 0 00.473-.66L9.337 6.677A1 1 0 008.39 6H7.207a1 1 0 00-.947.678zM7.736 8.08h.051l1.364 4.453H6.372L7.736 8.08zm11.113 2.043v-.327a1 1 0 011-1H20a1 1 0 011 1v6.078a1 1 0 01-1 1h-.151a1 1 0 01-1-1v-.312h-.088c-.392.874-1.232 1.439-2.418 1.439-1.975 0-3.221-1.613-3.221-4.182 0-2.546 1.254-4.15 3.221-4.15 1.172 0 2.026.595 2.418 1.454h.088zm-.045 2.712c0-1.47-.685-2.404-1.754-2.404-1.068 0-1.725.92-1.725 2.404 0 1.491.657 2.395 1.725 2.395 1.076 0 1.754-.911 1.754-2.395z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span><span class="css-il1drd"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 000 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 000-1.419.987.987 0 00-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 00-1.406 0z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></span></span></button></div></div></div></div><span class="css-in63ti"></span></span><span class="css-ox6esc"><span class="css-ox6esc"><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button id="editor-toolbar__strong" aria-label="Bold Ctrl+B" aria-pressed="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+b" class="css-1muxtt6" data-testid="editor-toolbar__Bold" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M8 6h4.832C13.908 6 16 6.5 16 9c0 1.333-.333 2.167-1 2.5 1.333.333 2 1.333 2 3 0 .5 0 3.5-4 3.5H8a1 1 0 01-1-1V7a1 1 0 011-1zm1 10h3.5c1 0 2-.25 2-1.5s-1.104-1.5-2-1.5H9v3zm0-4.975h3c.504 0 2 0 2-1.525S12 8 12 8H9v3.025z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></button></div></div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button id="editor-toolbar__italic" aria-label="Italic Ctrl+I" aria-pressed="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+i" class="css-1muxtt6" data-testid="editor-toolbar__Italic" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M10 6h6a1 1 0 010 2h-6a1 1 0 110-2zM8 16h6a1 1 0 010 2H8a1 1 0 010-2zm4-8h2l-2 8h-2l2-8z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></button></div></div></span><span class="css-2i865c"><div class="css-x571cj"><div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="More formatting" class="css-1muxtt6" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><div class="css-ov1ktg"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M12 14a1.5 1.5 0 110-3 1.5 1.5 0 010 3zm-4.5 0a1.5 1.5 0 110-3 1.5 1.5 0 010 3zm9 0a1.5 1.5 0 110-3 1.5 1.5 0 010 3z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></div></span></button></div></div></div></div><span class="css-in63ti"></span></span></span><span class="css-2i865c"><div class="css-x571cj"><div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Lists" class="css-1muxtt6" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span class="css-2i865c"><span role="img" aria-label="Lists" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M6 8c0-.552.444-1 1-1 .552 0 1 .444 1 1 0 .552-.444 1-1 1-.552 0-1-.444-1-1zm5-1h6a1 1 0 010 2h-6a1 1 0 010-2zm-5 5c0-.552.444-1 1-1 .552 0 1 .444 1 1 0 .552-.444 1-1 1-.552 0-1-.444-1-1zm5-1h6a1 1 0 010 2h-6a1 1 0 010-2zm-5 5c0-.552.444-1 1-1 .552 0 1 .444 1 1 0 .552-.444 1-1 1-.552 0-1-.444-1-1zm5-1h6a1 1 0 010 2h-6a1 1 0 010-2z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span><span class="css-il1drd"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 000 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 000-1.419.987.987 0 00-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 00-1.406 0z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></span></span></button></div></div></div></div><span class="css-in63ti"></span></span><span class="css-ox6esc"><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-label="Link Ctrl+K" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+k" class="css-1muxtt6" data-testid="Link" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span role="img" aria-label="Link" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M12.654 8.764a.858.858 0 01-1.213-1.213l1.214-1.214a3.717 3.717 0 015.257 0 3.714 3.714 0 01.001 5.258l-1.214 1.214-.804.804a3.72 3.72 0 01-5.263.005.858.858 0 011.214-1.214c.781.782 2.05.78 2.836-.005l.804-.803 1.214-1.214a1.998 1.998 0 00-.001-2.831 2 2 0 00-2.83 0l-1.215 1.213zm-.808 6.472a.858.858 0 011.213 1.213l-1.214 1.214a3.717 3.717 0 01-5.257 0 3.714 3.714 0 01-.001-5.258l1.214-1.214.804-.804a3.72 3.72 0 015.263-.005.858.858 0 01-1.214 1.214 2.005 2.005 0 00-2.836.005l-.804.803L7.8 13.618a1.998 1.998 0 00.001 2.831 2 2 0 002.83 0l1.215-1.213z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></span></span></button></div></div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-label="Mention @" aria-keyshortcuts="Shift+2 Space" class="css-1muxtt6" data-testid="Mention" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span role="img" aria-label="Mention" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M12.062 13.93c-.904 0-1.451-.734-1.451-1.945 0-1.226.538-1.952 1.466-1.952.928 0 1.422.764 1.422 1.967 0 1.195-.502 1.93-1.438 1.93M12 5c-3.925 0-7 3.075-7 7 0 4.596 3.522 7 7 7 .874 0 1.614-.09 2.26-.279a.751.751 0 00-.42-1.44c-.508.147-1.11.22-1.84.22-2.648 0-5.5-1.722-5.5-5.5 0-3.085 2.417-5.5 5.5-5.5 3.24 0 5.5 1.952 5.5 4.75 0 2.045-1.043 3-1.748 3-.008 0-.752-.11-.752-.75v-4a.75.75 0 10-1.5 0v.187c-.346-.585-1.016-.952-1.795-.952C10.102 8.736 9 10.04 9 11.938c0 1.984 1.103 3.312 2.753 3.312.865 0 1.51-.387 1.865-1.076.334 1.016 1.37 1.576 2.132 1.576 1.598 0 3.25-1.683 3.25-4.5C19 7.628 16.058 5 12 5" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></button></div></div><span class="css-2i865c"><div class="css-x571cj"><div><div role="presentation"><div class="css-13cz8p3"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Insert /" aria-keyshortcuts="/" class="css-1muxtt6" tabindex="0" type="button" style="align-items: center;"><span class="css-18kgcs9"><span class="css-3efyhq"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M13 11V7a1 1 0 00-2 0v4H7a1 1 0 000 2h4v4a1 1 0 002 0v-4h4a1 1 0 000-2h-4z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span><span class="css-il1drd"><span aria-hidden="true" class="css-snhnyn" style="--icon-primary-color: currentColor; --icon-secondary-color: var(--ds-surface, #FFFFFF);"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"><path d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 000 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 000-1.419.987.987 0 00-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 00-1.406 0z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></span></span></span></button></div></div></div></div></span></span></div></div><div class="css-1d31zfz"></div></div></div><div data-testid="click-wrapper" class="css-1q3xxv2"><div class="ak-editor-content-area less-margin css-1nvq6sn"><div class="css-ov1ktg"></div><lt-highlighter contenteditable="false" style="display: none;" data-lt-linked="1"><lt-div spellcheck="false" class="lt-highlighter__wrapper" style="width: 442px !important; height: 23.9844px !important; transform: none !important; transform-origin: 221px 11.9922px !important; zoom: 1 !important; margin-top: 12px !important; margin-left: 8px !important;"><lt-div class="lt-highlighter__scroll-element" style="top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; width: 442px !important; height: 23.9844px !important;"></lt-div></lt-div></lt-highlighter><div class="ua-chrome ProseMirror" role="textbox" id="ak-editor-textarea" contenteditable="true" translate="no" data-gramm="false" aria-labelledby="description-label" data-lt-tmp-id="lt-164041" spellcheck="false" style="display: block;"><p><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"></p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

I'm making an extension for Google Chrome that should automatically fill this field with the text I want when the page loads. I noticed that when typing text manually, a  tag is generated where the typed text appears, but when trying to do it via JS the created task doesn't see that the field is filled in.
I tried adding the  tag, or dev TextContent
Also saw that there is a textarea type input inside. Tried changing its value, but it didn't help. TExt con

Try dispatching a change event or use the legacy document.execCommand, example.

@woxxom Thx a lot! I'm more of an amateur at this. I haven't heard of the method. Could you please tell me if using this method in today's day is acceptable in a relatively professional)  environment?

There's no such restriction.

@woxxom Sorry, I noticed that document.execCommand only works if you manually click on an item. As I understand it, the .focus() method is not triggered on the element right after onload, automatically focus works on the first input.  document.execCommand method works on the first input field.

The example I've linked shows how to focus the element.
